# java API source files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

In some eclipse installations I have noted that they are able to view all the source files inside a jar(may be if the jar has source files packaged in it or another jar for source?).

If we ctrl+click or f3 on a class type, then it shows the source code of the JAVA API for that class. Likewise for many classes. even for some third party classes like apache's. But in my installation i just get a white screen with the name of the jar and some mess of unreadable content. And also previously I have got javadocs of JAVA API very well before when i hover my mouse over the class or function names. But in my current installation even that is gone.

How to get java docs and source file viewing in eclipse? i am using eclipse juno... downloaded within 6months..

Comment: Do you have a Java JRE rather than the full JDK installed (look in the Preferences / Java / Installed JREs to see what Eclipse is using).

Comment: wow... super tip. that resolved the java docs thing. while typing this checked whether it resolved source viewing too... yes it did! you could have answered instead of commenting! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that Eclipse is using a full JDK rather than just a JRE. Look in `Preferences / Java / Installed JREs` to see what Eclipse is using.